# Two rows in a single row in mariadb, mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

let's say i have this

| id | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | Three |

and want to be like this

| id | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | Three |

my first table is just a representation of what actually I am encountering, everything will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens if there are more rows for the same id, with some other values? Please share your create table and insert queries as well.

Comment: It should be concatenated into one

Comment: [group_concat](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by the `id` column and the the max values of the other records

```
select id, 
       max(center) as center, 
       max(`right`) as `right`
from your_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by id and group_concat the columns like this

```
SELECT id, group_concat(`center`) as center, group_concat(`right`) as rights FROM `your_table` group by id;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9phZ7EpRUS4FNRBZRdSYZa/116